# What if I install redhat rpms into CentOS? Everything is fine?

Tags: rpm

I heard that there is a patch for CVE-6271, CVE-7169
- To redhat 5, bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4
- To centos 5, bash-3.2-33.el5_10.4

Now I'm wondering if I install redhat rpm into centos or vice versa.
Is that possible? Or more precisely, is that always possible without any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS packages are RedHat with the branding changed, therefore they should work on either as long as you keep to the same release.

If you're just changing a single package then it should be fine - just `yum install <local rpm file>`.

The downside of doing this is that you will not receive any update notficiation for the package as it isn't tied to a repository. Instead, you will need to periodically check for newer versions and install them manually.

If you're really cautious (sensible?) install an alternative shell and make sure you have an user whose login shell is set to this.

It's even possible to change your whole system over from [RHEL to CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide).

Comment: I think manual updating is a big downside, (if there is no special reason) I'll rather get the same brand rpm. :) Thank you very much.